# "Working" script returning Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, css-selectors, nodes

I'm building a page that first gets the HTML data from an external page (Not cross domain), then after the first function completes, it runs a function which is a sideshow. It works... More or less...

The problem that I'm having is that after 5 or 6 slides, the whole thing gets messy and then everything disappears. When checking the console, I found the following message:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:6297:21)
    at domManip (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:6066:14)
    at jQuery.fn.init.after (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:6295:10)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/go/scripts/jqueryautoscroll/autoscroll.js:41:47)
    at HTMLDivElement.opt.complete (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:7900:12)
    at fire (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:3232:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:3362:7)
    at tick (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:7755:14)
    at jQuery.fx.tick (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.js:8069:9)
```

I presume it has something to do with the `container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));`
So I tried commenting all the lines, the error was gone, but then the sliders wouldn't change.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$("#jobshome").load("jobs/newest-jobs .js-toprow", function(){
    //rotation speed and timer
    var speed = 3000;
    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    var slides = $('.js-toprow');
    var container = $('#jobshome');
    var elm = container.find(':first-child').prop("tagName");
    var item_height = container.height();
    var previous = 'prevabc'; //id of previous button
    var next = 'nextabc'; //id of next button
    slides.height(item_height); //set the slides to the correct pixel height
    container.parent().height(item_height);
    container.height(slides.length * item_height); //set the slides container to the correct total height
    container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
    resetSlides(); 


    //if user clicked on prev button

    $('#buttonsabc a').click(function (e) {
        //slide the item

        if (container.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.target.id == previous) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1500, function () {
                container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
                resetSlides();
            });
        }

        if (e.target.id == next) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': item_height * -2
            }, 1500, function () {
                container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
                resetSlides();
            }
      );
    }
        //cancel the link behavior            
        return false;

    });

    //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it    
    container.parent().mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(run);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    });


    function resetSlides() {
        //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
        container.css({
            'top': -1 * item_height
        });
    }

});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
    jQuery('#nextabc').click();
}

});
```

```css
#carouselabc {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slidesabc {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

#areadoslideabc {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#slidesabcdef {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: lato, sans-serif;
}


/* Styling for prev and next buttons */

.btn-barabc {
  max-width: 346px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#buttonsabc {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  float: right;
}

#buttonsabc a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0 60px;
  color: #b14943;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 35px;
}

a#prevabc:hover,
a#next:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: .5px 0px #b14943;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselabc">
  <div class="btn-barabc">
    <div id="buttonsabc">
      <a id="prevabc" href="#">Previous</a>
      <a id="nextabc" href="#">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="slidesabc">
    <div id="jobshome"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot 1
[image: Screenshot #1]

Screenshot 2
[image: Screenshot #2]

This is how it starts
[image: This is how it starts]

Comment: Hello... Anyone?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it is rendered in the DOM tree?

Comment: Yes sir. Done. Please check it out.

Comment: Added one more screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to happen because of the nested selectors (`.js-toprow`) that are later moved.

Try replacing all the `.find()` (matches children any level deep) with `.children()` (matches only  immediate children).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#jobshome").load("jobs/newest-jobs .js-toprow", function(){
    //rotation speed and timer
    var speed = 3000;
    var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    var slides = $('.js-toprow');
    var container = $('#jobshome');
    var elm = container.children(':first-child').prop("tagName");
    var item_height = container.height();
    var previous = 'prevabc'; //id of previous button
    var next = 'nextabc'; //id of next button
    slides.height(item_height); //set the slides to the correct pixel height
    container.parent().height(item_height);
    container.height(slides.length * item_height); //set the slides container to the correct total height
    container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));
    resetSlides(); 


    //if user clicked on prev button

    $('#buttonsabc a').click(function (e) {
        //slide the item

        if (container.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (e.target.id == previous) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': 0
            }, 1500, function () {
                container.children(elm + ':first').before(container.children(elm + ':last'));
                resetSlides();
            });
        }

        if (e.target.id == next) {
            container.stop().animate({
                'top': item_height * -2
            }, 1500, function () {
                container.children(elm + ':last').after(container.children(elm + ':first'));
                resetSlides();
            }
      );
    }
        //cancel the link behavior            
        return false;

    });

    //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it    
    container.parent().mouseenter(function () {
        clearInterval(run);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
    });


    function resetSlides() {
        //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
        container.css({
            'top': -1 * item_height
        });
    }

});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
    jQuery('#nextabc').click();
}

});
```

Comment: It worked. 1 more question, why is it changing the background class color after it stops?

Comment: Don't worry about the answer acceptation, just tell me if you can help me with this one last thing (If not, it's ok). "Not sure what you mean", here you go https://fleamerica.com/, see for yourself the grey background changing color every time the slide advances and pauses for a while.

Comment: Your site is EU blocked. You could try putting related parts of the code on codepen and i'll see what i can do.

Comment: It won't work, due to the cross domain policy. What I can do is unblock it temporarily just so you might check it. Tell me when you're online.

Comment: It's unblocked. Please check it out.

Comment: Background changes because in your css you are using the rule for `:odd` and `:even` children. And then you are moving first/last element. Which breaks the count and makes item change from odd to even index and vice versa. (Example: Item is at index 3 - odd, then you add another item to the beginning of the container, that item is not at index 4 - even).

Comment: Also your `#slidesabc` height is incorrect, should be 220px.

Comment: Well, I need the background to be even and odd. Does it mean I should use jQuery for achieving that?

Comment: Yup, you would need to dynamically add classes based on which element is current and what background it has.

Comment: @Matt `resetSlides()` function.