# How can I style even and odd children in a dynamic list?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using

```
$('.js-toprow:nth-child(even)').css("background:", "#ddd");
$('.js-toprow:nth-child(odd)').css("background:", "#ff0000");
```

Inside the function:

```
function resetSlides() {
    container.css({
        'top': -1 * item_height
    });

// >> Using it here <<   
}
```

To make an element tree have two different colors.

The full code can be seen here (already solved): ["Working" script returning Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286193/working-script-returning-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-insertbefor/52287248?noredirect=1#comment91546675_52287248)

In this case the variable that should be styled is "slides", so I tried using `slides.css({'background': '#000'});` inside the function just for testing, and it worked, but I still need the even and odd.

Yes, I need to achieve that with jQuery only, because using CSS causes the children to be re-styled as new elements are inserted at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Why not use pure CSS to tackle this? JavaScript seems unnecessary in this case if all you are trying to do is set the `background-color`.

Comment: If you want to inline style elements as if even and odd were used, you will have to perform some filtering to select those that should get the event styling, vs the odd styling, and set the style accordingly

Comment: I'm doing this because I was using pure CSS. Check the page that has the full code, I said there "the grey background is changing color every time the slide advances and pauses for a while", which I was replied "Background changes because in your css you are using the rule for :odd and :even children. And then you are moving first/last element. Which breaks the count and makes item change from odd to even index and vice versa. (Example: Item is at index 3 - odd, then you add another item to the beginning of the container, that item is not at index 4 - even)."

Comment: so basically, I already found where I should make the change and already was able to make the change, except that I don't know how to use the `nth-child(odd)`, can you help me with this? Yes, in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the elements and test the index to determine if it is even or odd:

```
$('.js-toprow').each(function(index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) { // Even
      $(this).css('background', '#ddd');
    } else { // Odd
      $(this).css('background', '#ff0000');
    }        
});
```

The modulo operator returns the remainder of dividing two numbers, in this case `index` and `2`. Even number will always return `0`.

Comment: What I need to style is the parent. `.js-toprow` is the parent.

Comment: @Matt The `nth-child` stuff threw me. I updated my answer.

Comment: Worked, but there's a problem now. It's repeating a color after x number of elements. The color repeated is random. For example, now it shows two elements in a row with the same color.

Comment: Do you want to take a look at the web site to see what's happening?

Comment: @Matt Depending upon how you manipulate the DOM after this is run, you may wind up with colors repeating. You may have to play around with when this is run to achieve the desired effect.